# DBD::SQLite Placeholder for integer value in HAVING clause

Tags: sqlite, perl, casting, prepared-statement, dbi

Since similar statements using [DBD::mysql](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::mysql) seem to work fine, where is my mistake in using a placeholder for an integer in a `HAVING` clause, when using [DBD::SQLite](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::SQLite) as DBI driver?

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use 5.012;
use warnings;

use DBI;

my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:SQLite:dbname=/tmp/test.sqlite","","", {
    RaiseError => 1,
    sqlite_allow_multiple_statements => 1,
});

$dbh->do( <<'EOT' );
CREATE TABLE cd (
    id    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    title TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE artist (
    id   INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    name TEXT,
    cd   INTEGER,
    FOREIGN KEY (cd) REFERENCES cd (id)
);

INSERT INTO cd (title) VALUES ('foo');
INSERT INTO cd (title) VALUES ('bar');

INSERT INTO artist (name, cd) VALUES ('max fob', 1);
INSERT INTO artist (name, cd) VALUES ('max baz', 1);
EOT

my $sth1 = $dbh->prepare(<<'EOT');
   SELECT cd.title
     FROM cd
LEFT JOIN artist ON artist.cd = cd.id
    WHERE artist.name LIKE ?
 GROUP BY cd.title
   HAVING count( artist.cd ) = 2
EOT

my $sth2 = $dbh->prepare(<<'EOT');
   SELECT cd.title
     FROM cd
LEFT JOIN artist ON artist.cd = cd.id
    WHERE artist.name LIKE ?
 GROUP BY cd.title
   HAVING count( artist.cd ) = ?
EOT

$sth1->execute('max%');
# says 'hit'
say 'sth1: hit' if $sth1->fetch;

$sth2->execute('max%', 2);
# stays silent
say 'sth2: hit' if $sth2->fetch;
```

Thank you, DDL.

Comment: Which errors do you get?

Comment: @Håkon Hægland, No error. Just no results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `?` placeholder is always replaced in the prepared statement by a string (like `'2'`), which for SQLite has **no affinity**.

From [Datatypes In SQLite/Affinity Of Expressions](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#affinity_of_expressions) is derived that an expression like `count(artist.cd)`, although it is documented that it returns an integer, has **no affinity**.

Also, from [Datatypes In SQLite/Type Conversions Prior To Comparison](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#type_conversions_prior_to_comparison) is derived that 2 operands with no affinity are compared without any implicit data type conversion.

For SQLite the expression `2 = '2'` returns `false`.

This is why you must apply data type conversion to the `?` placeholder to convert it to a numeric value, which you can do with:

```
HAVING count( artist.cd ) = ? + 0
```

Also, not related to your problem, the `WHERE` clause in your query makes the `LEFT` join behave like an `INNER` join, because it is applied to a column of the *right* table and filters out any non matching rows.

Comment: Re "*A `?` placeholder is always replaced in the prepared statement by a string*", I showed otherwise in my answer

Comment: Re "*the `WHERE` clause in your query makes the `LEFT` join behave like an `INNER` join*", Could you add the improvement to your answer? (I think it's `LEFT JOIN ( SELECT ... FROM artist WHERE ...  ) AS filtered_artist ON ...`?)

Comment: @ikegami what you showed in your question is that unless the ? is converted to integer the query does not work which is correct. What you also say is that you *don't know why it doesn't work*. I explain in my answer why it does not work: because "A ? placeholder is always replaced in the prepared statement by a string" which has no affinity. About the join, yes this is one way to write it or: `SELECT cd.title FROM cd LEFT JOIN artist ON artist.cd = cd.id AND artist.name LIKE ?`

Comment: @ikegami your code uses `bind_param(2, 2, DBI::SQL_INTEGER)` which I assume binds the parameter 2 as an integer. The OP's code does not do an explicit binding with data type and this is why it is replaced by the string '2'. This is why you need in your 2nd solution to cast to an integer.

Comment: @ikegami You posted a comment where you question my claim that: *A ? placeholder is always replaced in the prepared statement by a string*. You say that you proved this claim wrong. No you didn't.  You proved it's true, because in order to make the OP's work you either use data type binding or casting to integer. If my claim was wrong then the OP's code would work as it is.

Comment: Which is it, placeholders are always replaced with a string, or `bind_param` made it so the placeholder was replaced with something other than string? These two claims of yours can't both be true. **Your claim that "a `?` placeholder is always replaced in the prepared statement by a string (like '2'), which for SQLite has no affinity" is false.** It might be the default, but I showed how you can change this.

Comment: @ikegami There is no `bind_param` in the OP's code and this is what my answer is about. You are the one who uses `bind_param` because **otherwise the ? placeholder will be replaced by the string '2'**. I can't do anything more about your ignorance which you admit in your answer. Read SQLite's documentation about affinities and then come back.

Comment: Otherwise or always? In your answer, you say always. Now you say otherwise. I showed your comments are correct and that your answer is wrong.

Comment: @ikegami your original answer started with: *I don't know why it doesn't work as-is...* and now after I posted my answer you changed to: *I don't know why the placeholder is treated as a string...* which means that you learned something from my answer which is correct because it is about the OP's code and not your code.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why the placeholder is treated as a string<sup>[1]</sup>, but you can get the code to work by making SQLite treat the value as an integer. Both of the following solutions are means of achieving this:

```perl
my $sth2 = $dbh->prepare(<<'EOT');
   SELECT cd.title
     FROM cd
LEFT JOIN artist ON artist.cd = cd.id
    WHERE artist.name LIKE ?
 GROUP BY cd.title
   HAVING count( artist.cd ) = ?
EOT

$sth2->bind_param(1, 'max%');
$sth2->bind_param(2, 2, DBI::SQL_INTEGER);
$sth2->execute();
```

```perl
my $sth2 = $dbh->prepare(<<'EOT');
   SELECT cd.title
     FROM cd
LEFT JOIN artist ON artist.cd = cd.id
    WHERE artist.name LIKE ?
 GROUP BY cd.title
   HAVING count( artist.cd ) = CAST( ? AS INTEGER )
EOT

$sth2->execute('max%', 2);
```

---

1. The other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71068099/589924) claims that placeholders are always treated as strings. Not only is this not an explanation, it's not even true. This unbacked claim of theirs is obviously false since `bind_param` can cause placeholders to be treated as something other than a string.

Comment: The OP's code does not use `bind_param`. You are using it. Why? Because you if you don't the `?` placeholder will be replaced by the string '2'. Is that clear?

Comment: @forpas Yes, that's a good, clear rephrasing of my answer. However, I think my answer is already clear. Are you suggesting some kind of change? If so, could you identify the problem?

Comment: @forpas No, it's not related to my comprehension. I always knew it didn't work because it was treated as a string. That's why I provided solutions that forced it to be a number. The rephrase was primarily to assist your ability to understanding what I wrote, but also for others that might have the same need for having things spelled out.

Comment: @forpas yes, I know what my answer was. I wrote it, and it's can viewed by following the link right below the answer.  /// Re "*If you always knew you would have mentioned that also*",  I didn't know. I still don't know. That's why my answer said as much and still does.   [Comment flagged. user is retaliating with off-topic nonsense comments for pointing out an error in their answer]

Comment: Where did you see in my answer that I *provide an explanation why placeholders are used as strings*? My answer states that placeholders are replaced by strings. I don't provide an explanation for that because I don't know the inner mechanics of the replacement. My explanation is about how SQLite behaves when it compares integers to strings.

Comment: @forpas, Re "*Where did you see in my answer that I provide an explanation why placeholders are used as strings?*", I've been quite clear that you *don't* provide such an explanation.

Comment: Better now that you edited.